# Can we set non recommended values like 61 as DSCP value for QoS (Quality of services)

Tags: networking, router, cisco, qos

I am wondering if we can set/mark a packet header with non-recommended DSCP value. With Wireshark I can see that packet is marked "Unknown DSCP". So my question is "is it necessary to set the recommended value of DSCP always ?

For Example. If I am setting DSCP to 62 its showing unknown DSCP. Whereas if I set 32 or 40 or other mentioned in list , it's giving me name of proper class.

Will the packed be dropped or sent with default priority ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wireshark says, it's "unknown", not "malformed". It's perfetly OK to use a non-recommended DSCP values: as is often (if not always) the case you have a range for experimental values, for instance if you work at Cisco or Huawey and develop new equipment.

> 6. IANA Considerations
>
> The DSCP field within the DS field is capable of conveying 64 distinct
> codepoints.  The codepoint space is divided into three pools for the
> purpose of codepoint assignment and management: **a pool of 32
> RECOMMENDED codepoints** (Pool 1) to be assigned by Standards Action as
> defined in [CONS], **a pool of 16 codepoints (Pool 2) to be reserved
> for experimental or Local Use (EXP/LU)** as defined in [CONS], and a
> pool of 16 codepoints (Pool 3) which are initially available for
> experimental or local use, but which should be preferentially utilized
> for standardized assignments if Pool 1 is ever exhausted.

(emphasis mine)

As to what happens to traffic with such non-standard values, it's treated with default priority by equipment that do not recognize it:

> 3. Differentiated Services Field Definition
>
> [...]
>
> Packets received with an unrecognized codepoint SHOULD be forwarded as if they were
> marked for the Default behavior (see Sec. 4), and their codepoints
> should not be changed.  Such packets MUST NOT cause the network node
> to malfunction.

So it is indeed experimental: don't expect interoperability, it will be ignored (but preserved, though).

Source: rfc2474 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2474

Comment: Thanks for clarification, now I can assume my packets are at least safe. However not necessarily prioritized  .  

One follow up Question: So we can use any DSCP value between 0-63 on local network and map it to some corresponding priorities ? In live network not experimental implememntation.